# FabricJS: How to remove/change object selection points

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

This is a problem I have come across while using FabricJS. When we select an object it shows the transform points around the object. Sometimes those points look too bigger than it should be when the canvas is small. How can I reduce the size of those transform/selection points and remove any point in the global scenario? I want to do this so that when scaling objects their shape won't be distorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by trying out.

```
canvas.on('object:selected', function (options) {
    options.target.set({
        cornerSize: 5,
        transparentCorners: false
    });
    options.target.setControlsVisibility({
          'mt': false, 'mb': false, 'ml': false, 'mr': false
    });
});
```